# I cannot log in to any of Gnome desktops on Fedora 37, but all other users can

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, gdm

I am running Linux on a completely updated Fedora 37 system. I encountered a problem a few days after my latest update (note that I had logged on and off and rebooted my machine several times between the last update and when the following problem occurred).

I had logged off the previous evening, so I was at the login menu screen (where the user accounts are presented). When I tried to log in to my account selecting either the "Gnome Classic with Xorg" or "Gnome on Xorg" desktops, I was greeted by the white screen of death message:

"Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.
Please log out and try again.
[Log Out]"

At that point, all I could do was hit the [Log Out] button to return to the login menu.

If I tried to login with Gnome or Gnome Classic (which use Wayland), I was returned immediately to the login menu screen.

Logging in to Plasma (KDE) works fine with either Plasma X11 or Plasma Wayland.

No other users have this problem, that is they can all login using any of the above mentioned desktops. That suggests that something in my Gnome configuration has been corrupted, but I have not knowingly done anything to it.

Attempted remedies so far:

1. I tried rebooting several times and the problem persists.
2. I have tried moving the ~/.cache file to ~/.cache_old, then rebooting but that did nothing.
3. I tried typing from a terminal:
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-user-extensions true,
   then rebooted. It made no difference.
4. I tried rm -rf .gnome gnome2 .gconf, followed by rebooting. It made no difference.

I have spent a lot of time in the last several days looking on line. I can find somewhat similar problems, but they are different enough that they do not relate to mine and do not offer a solution. Generally in those problems, all users are effected the same way or only one of the two effects is present (white screen of death or immediate return to login screen, not both).

Would anyone have any ideas on how to recover? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I tried moving ~/.config to ~/.config_old and rebooting. There was no change to login problem.

Comment: Please create a new profiile/login for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I created a new profile/login for myself that did not have the problem. But I now have to reconfigure that profile to what I was using before. That's a lot of work. I was hoping that there would be certain configuration files that might be causing my problem, so that I could just replace or repair those files or parts of them.

Comment: I had a similar problem (XFCE refused to load) but I had to solve it manually by deleting config files basically one by one until I found the one which caused the issue. There's no other way.